# Windows Registry - HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell

Tags: windows, windows-registry, path

I recently learned about the [Registry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry) in Windows, more specifically about the directory `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell`

There you can make a key called eg. `Test` and another key called `command` and there you can make a new String Value linked to some .bat File and it will execute when you click on a Folder and select Test.

Source: [pureinfotech](https://pureinfotech.com/delete-large-folder-fast-windows-10/#delete_large_folder_fast_context_menu).

But I have a question. This will happen if you click *on* a Folder, eg.
**Click on Folder**:
[image: Click on Folder]

My Question: Is there some HKEY Path that will execute when you are in the folder, and click in any free Space, e.g.
**Click in Folder**:
[image: Click in Folder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background` contains the actions added to the
context menu when you right-click on the "background" empty space while in a folder

You have to add here the empty string value of `NoWorkingDirectory`,
and the `%1` in the command becomes a `%V`.

The following example comes from
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4902253/165358),
to add `console2` to the empty space context menu:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\console2]
@="Open Console2 Here"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\console2\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Console\\console.exe -d \"\"%V\"\""
```

Comment: Thanks, working!